# Vertically aligning animated divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have three buttons that set different output text when clicked and I'm trying to use W3.CSS animations to "slide" the text in and out. I almost have it working using two separate divs but cannot get them to align correctly under the buttons; the div for every other button click displays lower than the previous one.

I've tried `float`, `vertical-align: top`, `display: inline-block`, and a few other things so far but either used them incorrectly or something else (a conflicting parent div style, maybe?) is causing problems.

[Image with a button's output displaying right under the buttons (as it should)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMRyK.png)

[Image with the next button's output displaying lower than the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsHkZ.png)

I trimmed code that wasn't relevant while also leaving what was necessary to show the div structure for this particular section.

- HTML: The divs with IDs `old_output` and `new_output` are what I'm trying to align below the buttons
- CSS: `div.button_output_container` and `div.button_output` are used for the output divs and their container
- JS: Handles button clicks, decides which animation should be used, and sets the output text (aside from demonstrating the issue I think it's mostly irrelevant)

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n4fk7jeb/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I totally understand your alignment requirement,
but if you just want your divs to render on the same height, you could opt for `position:absolute` like so:

```
div.button_output_container {
  position: relative; 
}

div.button_output {
    margin: 16px 24px;
    width: 450px;
    position: absolute; 
}
```